# Umbraco Backoffice not registering changes made to custom property editor

Tags: visual-studio, caching, properties, editor, umbraco

I'm new to Umbraco and creating my own property editors. I am currently trying to implement the example from the Umbraco Belle site:

https://umbraco.github.io/Belle/#/tutorials/CreatingAPropertyEditor

I managed to get it working, showing the alert message when I add the property editor to my document type.

However after I've added the Pagedown-bootstrap files, saved and rebuilt the project, as well as refreshing my browser cache, it still gives me the alert message from before when adding the editor. I tried recreating the datatype in the developer section as well, but this gives me the same result.

I've no clue why this happens and how to fix it. Is there something about the way Umbraco caches data that I am unaware of?

Comment: It will probably be your browser caching the files. Try a hard reset OR edit your web.config (add two blank lines and save again) this should force the App to restart.

Comment: When developing property editors for Umbraco, I often use this chrome extension to clear caches: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache/cppjkneekbjaeellbfkmgnhonkkjfpdn

Angular seems to sometimes cache templates very hard, and this extension seems to clear that.

Answer (score 3):

You could try updating the clientdependency number in Config/ClientDependency.config

Update the version number below by 1

```
<clientDependency version="{version number}" fileDependencyExtensions=".js,.css" loggerType="Umbraco.Web.UI.CdfLogger, umbraco">
```

Comment: This is a good answer. I'd like to add a little more detail in case anyone is curious. When your umbraco site is running with `<compilation debug="false" >`, Umbraco caches all of the backoffice css and javascript using ClientDependency. You have to uptick the clientDependency version to refresh this cache. You'll notice that when you install packages or upgrade umbraco, this version number is automatically adjusted to bust that cache. That's why you don't notice this problem when you upgrade umbraco or install packages.

Comment: This did not work for me. Same old html and JS file is being used.